# Even spacing of a numeric vector in R-Markdown

Tags: r, statistics

I am currently in an intermediate statistics class. I ran into a problem in my homework assignment and it is as follows:

From the assignment: "Create a vector x with these 25 observations of BMI for patients with cystic fibrosis...

68, 65, 64, 67, 93, 68, 89, 69, 67, 68, 89, 90, 93, 93, 66, 70, 70, 92, 69, 72, 86, 86, 97, 71, 95

The parts I would like help with:

a. Create a histogram going from 60-100 with breaks at 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100."

b. Compute the percentage of observations that fall into the following classes:

1. 60-65
2. 65-70
3. 70-75
4. 75-80
5. 80-85
6. 85-90
7. 90-95
8. 95-100
   total 100%

I created an object named `cyst_fibro_sample` to contain the observations. The assignment instructs us to use R to compute some basic statistics such as five number summaries, interquartile range, and standard deviation. I am using the built in `hist()` function as I have no variables and only observations to plot and I don't know how to plot the observations using `ggplot()`

`hist(x, breaks = 60,65,70...)` I would like to avoid doing punching in all the values by hand as this is grossly inefficient. However, I can't seem the vector operation for even spacing.

I would like for that argument to be `hist(x, breaks = c(60:100, increasing by = 5)`

For part b of the assignment, I think we are being asked to compute the density of each category of observation but I am not sure.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `seq(60, 100, 5)` will give you a vector with the desired numbers

Comment: @user12728748, that was exactly what I was after, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `seq()` function in my breaks argument in the base histogram function in R.

```
hist(x, breaks = seq(60, 100, 5)
```

I also figured out how to compute the percentages for each of the bounds given in the assignment.

```
sum((x >= 60, & x < 65)/length(x)) * 100
```

I saved each of the percentages as objects, and I would like to make a simple data frame out of them.

Answer (score 2):

I've used the `cars` dataset here, but by using a function to detect the bounds, we can generate a vector of breaks/bins using `seq` to produce the histogram, and calculate the density using `cut`.

```
data <- cars

make_bins <- function(data, m = 5) {
  rounded <- round(data/m) * m
  bins <- seq(min(rounded), max(rounded), by = m)
  return(bins)
}

bins <- make_bins(data$dist)

hist(data$dist, bins)

data$bins <- cut(data$dist, bins, include.lowest = TRUE)
dens <- table(data$bins)/nrow(data)
print(dens)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using the `cars` dataset from the `ggplot2` package.

How about using `scale_x_continuous` from the `ggplot2` package with `seq`?

In your case, `seq(from = 60, to = 100, by = 5)`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

cars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = dist))+
  geom_histogram() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 120, by = 20))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Original histogram:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

cars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = dist))+
  geom_histogram()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I would like to use `ggplot()` but the assignment only gave us the observations and nothing else to work with. I am unfamiliar with using `ggplot()` for only observations.